# Upload custom jacket lining magento plugin

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options, plugin

I need to let customers upload image and customise the lining of the jackets and cotes with it. I couldn't find a plugin for it. 
Does it even exist? Any alternatives, or I should start creating it by myself?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom options for this: There is a **File** input type available.

You can even define allowed file extensions and/or a maximum size for images (if needed).

[image]